# ¿cómo hago para que mi proyecto que tiene Java server Faces no ejecute al principio un xhtml?

Tags: html, netbeans, web, jsp

Buen día gente, soy nuevo en la comunidad y quería dar las gracias por las tantas veces que me han ayudado, ahora me he creado una cuenta para tanto preguntar como aportar en esta hermosa página.

Bueno lo que pasa es que en mi proyecto debo de implementar una funcionalidad en Java Server Faces, originalmente solo estoy usando Servlets y JSP... y ahora que implementé el framework para hacer mi funcionalidad, cuando ejecuto el proyecto no me abre automáticamente a mi index.html, sino que intenta abrir en el index.xhtml (Digo que intenta porque borré las páginas predeterminadas de framework, osea el index.xhtml y el WelcomeToPrimeFaces.xhtml)

¿Cómo soluciono el problema? espero sus respuestas y gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

Hacer este cambio en el web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
   <param-value>*.html</param-value>
</context-param>
```